# Is there a possibility to programmatically trigger item action in ListView, like when you dobuleclick on it?

Tags: winforms, listview, action

I was searching all over the place but I couldn't find an answer. I need to fire up an ListView item action, so it would rise the ItemActivate event. For now, it's only possible using ENTER key or double click... I would like to know if I could programmatically do that, something like :

```
listView.Items[int].Activate();
```

This doesn't work of course, because that function Activate() is not implemented there. For example, I couldn't find how to trigger buttons programmatically, but there it was, in the context menu which appears while you type:

```
buttonX.PerformClick();
```

...and it would trigger the button_click event. I wonder if there's something similar in the ListView control for triggering items inside of it ? I want it to raise this event programmatically and not by mouse doubleclick or Enter key on the keyboard...

```
private void myListView_ItemActivate(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.itemactivate(v=vs.110).aspx), the EventHandler in the ListView should be public. So you can raise the event with:

```
myListView.ItemActivate(myListView, EventArgs.Empty);
```

This way everyone who subscribed to this event will get notified.

---

Another way, of course, is to directly call your method:

```
myListView_ItemActivate(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

But this doesn't really classify as "raising the event", because you actually don't raise an event. You just call a method.

Comment: My idea was to reuse part of the code, which was executed via the event handler for a button click. I could do that by programmatically activating the button with the `button.PerformClick();` from anywhere in my code. Never occured to me that I could invoke the event method itself ! With the second line, I can call the method, giving it any object I wish, as a sender (listview, button...) thus giving me even more power to call that part of the program, than with PerformClick() or similar "action"... Thanx for your answer.